# Generating integers < limit

Tags: prolog, backtracking

I am trying to generate all integers (natural numbers) smaller than a limit, let's say 10.
I have a predicate `nat(X)` which produces all numbers from 0 to infinity.

Now my problem is, if I do:

```
nat10(X) :- nat(X), X =< 10.
```

This will never terminate, as it tries to find other solutions with `nat(X)` until infinity.

I need a construct that let's me fail the whole predicate if one subgoal fails. How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending upon the problem being solved, you might want to consider constraint logic programming over finite domains (CLPFD).

But in this context, you need just prevent Prolog from backtracking if `X > 10`. The current predicate `nat10/1` has no such constraint, so we'll add it:

```
nat10(X) :- nat(X), ( X > 10 -> !, fail ; true ).
```

So if `X > 10`, we do a cut (`!`) to prevent backtracking to `nat(X)` (thus avoiding generating natural numbers above `10` infinitely) and then simply `fail`. Otherwise, we succeed (`true`).

```
| ?- nat10(X).

X = 1 ? ;

X = 2 ? ;

...

X = 9 ? ;

X = 10 ? ;

(3 ms) no
| ?-
```

Comment: Could you explain why the explicit cut is needed here? `->` is already a `soft' cut.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf the cut is necessary to prevent prolog from infinitely attempting further solutions after it gets past `10`. If you leave it out, it will continue *ad infinitum*.

Comment: You need the cut, but you can replace the `->` with a comma.

Comment: Another small improvement is to cut a bit earlier, namely before returning the 10: `nat10(X) :- nat(X), ( X>=10, !, X=<10 ; true ).`

Answer (score 3):

If you can use [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd), then this answer is for you!

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
```

Simply try:

```
nat10(X) :-
   X in 0..10,
   indomain(X).
```